# Getting checkable list view into fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, android-fragments

I am trying to have a checkable list view fragment pop up with a button at the top of the list view.  After user clicks an item in the navigation menu, the main activity will be populated with my button and list view fragment.  I'm getting 'invoke virtual method' error, even though the element in declared. Here's some code.

**My list fragment class:**

```
public class ThingsManager extends Fragment {

ArrayList<String> selectedItems;
ListView checkable_list;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(layout.things_manager_fragment, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    //create an ArrayList object to store selected items
    selectedItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    //create an instance of ListView
    checkable_list.findViewById(R.id.checkable_list);
    //set multiple selection mode
    checkable_list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    String[] things_factory = {"Sports", "Politics", "Food", "Television", "Movies", "Fashion",
            "Theoretical Physics"};
    //supply data itmes to ListView
    //ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, R.id.things_check, things_factory);
    ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, things_factory);
    checkable_list.setAdapter(aa);
    //set OnItemClickListener
    checkable_list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // selected item
            String selectedItem = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
            if(selectedItems.contains(selectedItem))
                selectedItems.remove(selectedItem); //remove deselected item from the list of selected items
            else
                selectedItems.add(selectedItem); //add selected item to the list of selected items
        }
    });
}

public ThingsManager() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
}
```

**List fragment layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ThingsManager">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/things_manager_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Things Manager"
    android:textSize="25dp"/>

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/checkable_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Should I be controlling the listview in MainActivity or in the `FragmentClass`   ?

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: post your logcat

Answer (score 0):

Move your all your view initialization and listview setup code from `onActivityCreated` to  `onCreateView` method.

And your this statement

```
//create an instance of ListView
checkable_list.findViewById(R.id.checkable_list);
```

is wrong. You have to find `ListView` from the view you have inflated in `onCreateView`.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
   View rootView =  inflater.inflate(layout.things_manager_fragment, container, false);
   init(rootView);
   return rootView;
}

public void init(View rootView){


   //create an ArrayList object to store selected items
   selectedItems = new ArrayList<String>();
   //create an instance of ListView
   checkable_list = rootView.findViewById(R.id.checkable_list);
   //set multiple selection mode
   checkable_list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
   String[] things_factory = {"Sports", "Politics", "Food", "Television", "Movies", "Fashion",
        "Theoretical Physics"};
   //supply data itmes to ListView
   //ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, R.id.things_check, things_factory);
   ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, things_factory);
   checkable_list.setAdapter(aa);
   //set OnItemClickListener
   checkable_list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // selected item
        String selectedItem = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
        if(selectedItems.contains(selectedItem))
            selectedItems.remove(selectedItem); //remove deselected item from the list of selected items
        else
            selectedItems.add(selectedItem); //add selected item to the list of selected items
    }
   });

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this'll help

Comment: It didn't work, giving me an error on init(rootView); and still saying the virtual method error.  Just to let you know man.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.widget.ListView.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference          

(My bad for the lateness)

Comment: The first instance is on init(rootView), the second is on checkable_list